# iOS - keyboard global icon causes a crash

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, right-to-left

I am calling the below method in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, where the current user language is set to **"ar"**.

```
func configureInterfaceLayoutDirection() {
    if Utility.userLanguage == "en" {
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceLeftToRight
    } else {
        UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
    }
}
```

so whenever I press on keyobard global icon the app crashes for unknown reason.